How do I reuse the SCSS mixins from another style file to work with my classes and style them according to their resolutions?
I have a type.scss file that I need to use to reference various stylings for the fonts.
// type.scss

@use 'queries' as *;

$font-rubik: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
$font-inter: 'Inter', sans-serif;

// Define typography for desktop
$desktop: (
        h1: (font: $font-rubik, size: 64px, weight: bold),
        h2: (font: $font-rubik, size: 48px, weight: bold),
        h3: (font: $font-rubik, size: 40px, weight: bold),
        h4: (font: $font-rubik, size: 32px, weight: bold),
        p-large: (font: $font-inter, size: 24px, weight: semibold),
        p-medium: (font: $font-inter, size: 24px, weight: regular),
        button: (font: $font-rubik, size: 18px, weight: semibold)
);

// Define typography for tablet
$tablet: (
        h1: (font: $font-rubik, size: 52px, weight: bold),
        h2: (font: $font-rubik, size: 32px, weight: bold),
        h3: (font: $font-rubik, size: 24px, weight: bold),
        h4: (font: $font-rubik, size: 18px, weight: bold),
        p-large: (font: $font-inter, size: 14px, weight: semibold),
        p-medium: (font: $font-inter, size: 12px, weight: regular),
        button: (font: $font-rubik, size: 12px, weight: semibold)
);

// Define typography for mobile
$mobile: (
        h1: (font: $font-rubik, size: 32px, weight: bold),
        h2: (font: $font-rubik, size: 24px, weight: bold),
        h3: (font: $font-rubik, size: 18px, weight: bold),
        h4: (font: $font-rubik, size: 14px, weight: bold),
        p-large: (font: $font-inter, size: 12px, weight: semibold),
        p-medium: (font: $font-inter, size: 12px, weight: regular),
        button: (font: $font-rubik, size: 12px, weight: semibold)
);

// Mixin to apply responsive typography
@mixin typography($device) {
    h1 { font-family: map-get(map-get($device, h1), font); font-size: map-get(map-get($device, h1), size); font-weight: map-get(map-get($device, h1), weight); }
    h2 { font-family: map-get(map-get($device, h2), font); font-size: map-get(map-get($device, h2), size); font-weight: map-get(map-get($device, h2), weight); }
    h3 { font-family: map-get(map-get($device, h3), font); font-size: map-get(map-get($device, h3), size); font-weight: map-get(map-get($device, h3), weight); }
    h4 { font-family: map-get(map-get($device, h4), font); font-size: map-get(map-get($device, h4), size); font-weight: map-get(map-get($device, h4), weight); }
    p.large { font-family: map-get(map-get($device, p-large), font); font-size: map-get(map-get($device, p-large), size); font-weight: map-get(map-get($device, p-large), weight); }
    p.medium { font-family: map-get(map-get($device, p-medium), font); font-size: map-get(map-get($device, p-medium), size); font-weight: map-get(map-get($device, p-medium), weight); }
    button { font-family: map-get(map-get($device, button), font); font-size: map-get(map-get($device, button), size); font-weight: map-get(map-get($device, button), weight); } 
}

Media queries for responsive design
body {
  @include typography($desktop); // Default styles for desktop
}

// Tablet Styles
@media (max-width: 992px) and (min-width: 769px) { // Target tablets between these widths
  body {
    @include typography($tablet);
  }
}

// Mobile Styles
@media (max-width: 768px) { // Target mobile devices up to 768px
  body {
    @include typography($mobile);
  }
}

I've imported this into another scss file via @use '../../css/type.scss' as *; and am trying to include the typography into a few of the classes, for example:
// include.module.scss

.searchTitle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 32px;
  color: var(--main-color, #154058);
  align-self: stretch;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Rubik'; // all the hardcoded font stuff is what I'm trying to replace
  font-size: 24px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 150%; /* 36px */
}

This class styles a <p> tag <p className={classes.searchTitle}>Find education materials</p> and the idea is that including the mixin typographies would size and style the <p> tag accordingly based on the resolution. So I tried it but none of the styles applied.
I attempted to add a $class-name variable into the mixin too but that kept resulting in an error where I was missing an argument.
// type.scss

@mixin typography($device, $class-name) {
  .#{$class-name} {
    h1 { font-family: map-get(map-get($device, h1), font); font-size: map-get(map-get($device, h1), size); font-weight: map-get(map-get($device, h1), weight); }
    h2 { font-family: map-get(map-get($device, h2), font); font-size: map-get(map-get($device, h2), size); font-weight: map-get(map-get($device, h2), weight); }
    h3 { font-family: map-get(map-get($device, h3), font); font-size: map-get(map-get($device, h3), size); font-weight: map-get(map-get($device, h3), weight); }
    h4 { font-family: map-get(map-get($device, h4), font); font-size: map-get(map-get($device, h4), size); font-weight: map-get(map-get($device, h4), weight); }
    p.large { font-family: map-get(map-get($device, p-large), font); font-size: map-get(map-get($device, p-large), size); font-weight: map-get(map-get($device, p-large), weight); }
    p.medium { font-family: map-get(map-get($device, p-medium), font); font-size: map-get(map-get($device, p-medium), size); font-weight: map-get(map-get($device, p-medium), weight); }
    button { font-family: map-get(map-get($device, button), font); font-size: map-get(map-get($device, button), size); font-weight: map-get(map-get($device, button), weight); } 
  }
}

// include.module.scss

  @include typography($desktop, 'searchTitle');
  
  @media (max-width: 992px) and (min-width: 769px) { 
    @include typography($tablet, 'searchTitle');
  }

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    @include typography($mobile, 'searchTitle');
  }  

I'm kind of stuck here and I'm not sure how to fix the styling or actually have it take effect:
[sass] Missing argument $class-name.
    ╷
40  │ @mixin typography($device, $class-name) {
    │        ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ declaration
... │
54  │   @include typography($desktop); // Default styles for desktop
    │   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ invocation
    ╵
  src/css/type.scss 54:3                typography()
  src/css/type.scss 54:3                @use
  src/pages/Home/index.module.scss 1:1  root stylesheet

